# High performance Socket communication between TCPListener and a single Client program (C#)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I have a TCPListener server listens at dedicated port and there is one and only client connects with server. Client establishes connection with server and keeps continuing sending heartbeat messages with 60 seconds interval to keep it alive. Additionally it sends different types of request messages (first 4 bytes of each message reserved for size of message) which Server receives and passes socket to a **Task** (asynchronously) which performs a lengthy process including DB I/Os and returns back response by using same socket. It has been working fine but recently client has started sending 1000 requests asynchronously. Server responses back initial requests with a good pace but after entertaining around 100 requests response becomes slow. I solicit your expert opinion to make the response robust.

```
class ServerA
{
    .......
    .......
private void StartServer()
{
    ......
    socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
    Process(socket);
    .......
}

private void Process(Socket clientSocket)
{
    while(true)
    {
       byte[] msg = new byte[1024 * 1024];
       int totalMsgLength = clientSocket.Receive(msg);

       ClientRequest req = new ClientRequest();

       byte[] request = new byte[totalMsgLength];
       Buffer.BlockCopy(msg, 0, request, 0, totalMsgLength);
       req.HandleRequest(clientSocket, request); 

    }
}
}

class ClientRequest
{
byte[] request;
Socket clientSocket;

public void HandleRequest(Socket clientSocket,byte[] request)
{
    try
    {
        this.request = request;
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Entertain(null);
        });                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        .....
    }
}

private void Entertain(object callback)
{
    request = admin.PerformAction(ref request); //Long process
    clientSocket.Send(request); 
}
```

}

Comment: as a side note: you're not protecting `clientSocket.Send` from concurrent writes, which is bad

Comment: thanks for your expert opinion; what you suggest, how can this bad practice be avoided?

Comment: since you're using synchronous writes: `lock (clientSocket) { clientSocket.Send(request); }`

Comment: Do you think it is needed? The method Entertain( ) is being called every time from new object of "ClientRequest" class, so i believe that it is already thread safe.

Comment: The `ClientRequest` instance is irrelevant; you have one single client socket, and you're writing to it from multiple concurrent flows (via `Task.Run`). Yes, this is 100% absolutely required.

Comment: alright; got it;

Comment: TCP uses datagrams which are maximum of 1500 bytes.  Any messages larger than 1500 are broken into multiple datagrams.  When sending TCP and hop along the connection can break datagrams and combine datagrams as long as the size isn't larger than 1500 bytes.  Windows uses timers to move the datagrams from application to the interface and may split the messages in the middle.  So when you send a message it can be received in multiple chunks.  Your code cannot handle the multiple chunks.  TCP to be robust each message must either have a terminate char or have a byte count at beginning.

Comment: @jdweng re chunks: I raised the same concern in my answer, but (see comment) apparently that is just from simplified code; also: see "jumbo frames" - you can get much bigger than 1500 bytes per packet

Answer (score 1):

I would *imagine*, although we can't be sure, that a lot of this is due to the 1MiB buffer followed by a right-sized buffer that you allocate *every read*; scale that up to 1000 per second, and yes: that would hurt a lot. Effective buffer management is hard, and the simple approaches are only suitable for low-volume work.

I'm honestly more concerned with the blind receives, though; meaning: you mentioned TCP, and TCP is a *stream* protocol, not a *packet* protocol; there is no correlation whatsoever between how you receive buffers, and what was sent - *in terms of where each message ends*, especially for high volume / frequency; you need a "framing" protocol. Without that, what you send to `HandleRequest` could be incomplete messages, multiple messages, etc.

You should also have a `break;` in your loop if `totalMsgLength <= 0`.

The "pipelines" API would be a very effective solution to both problems; unfortunately, the "pipelines" API is only fully implemented for *servers*, but: clients can use Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial (nuget) to get the same features at clients (as the name suggests: it is not an official package). Since you're actually implementing a server here: Kestrel allows you to implement a *very* efficient arbitrary TCP server with the full pipelines API, simply by using `UseConnectionHandler<T>` for your TCP handler `T`.

Either way, the pipelines API provides:

- effective and efficient buffer management
- an excellent mechanism for handling incomplete frames without having to re-pack buffers

You can read more about the "pipelines" API in a 3.5-part blog series of mine [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) (it is *way* too big a topic to cover in a post here).

If rewriting it to use pipelines is too much, you can probably achieve a lot simply by moving the 1MiB buffer to *outside* the loop so it only gets allocated once. That still leaves the inner allocations; that could use the array-pool (`ArrayPool<byte>.Shared`), which gives *oversized* arrays, but you could pass a `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` or `ArraySegment<byte>` to the `HandleRequest` method to fix that.

That still leaves the framing problem, however. This is a *major* problem, and needs attention.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. To keep question simple, i tried to write code very less that obviously made some confusion. Client send ISO8583 message which is well defined and at start of each message it send length of message, so server reads socket and and breaks down on the basis of message length. However, I am looking into your suggestion of 1MiB. Will keep you updated on this. Thanks again.

Comment: I made changes as per your advice and deployed the upgrade at UAT but unfortunately did not get any improvement in performance. The same program runs fast at my laptop (i5+4 core+12 GB RAM) as all 1000 requests are being responded back in less than 2 min 30 seconds whilst the same program at UAT server (8 processors + 24GB RAM) takes around 15 minutes. Any other suggestion to isolate the problem?

Comment: @S.ATTA.M not without a lot more context and the ability to repro; however, question: is the local timing based on talking to the local machine? Latency and/or bandwidth may be the bottleneck here, which you won't be measuring similarly if you're using loopback

Comment: Yes, the whole development environment is set on a single machine unlike UAT environment where 3 machines are in actions connected via LAN. (Server, client and Oracle DB). As mentioned earlier, the actual problem is latency which starts well but gets increased over the time while handling 10 batches of requests consist of 1000 requests per batch. The project is huge so I did not explain everything to avoid distractions and to keep readers' focus on real issue. However, please ask freely if you need further info.

Comment: @S.ATTA.M you can't fix latency through code; you can *mitigate* latency issues, but that requires very specific design approaches such as message pipelining, i.e. instead of "request, response, request, response" (for 5 requests) the client might fire off 5 requests and then await 5 responses. That's *way* more involved than can reasonably be answered from example code, though; the details *really, really* matter.